# How can I fix these intermittent problems with wi-fi on my iMac?

Tags: macos, mac, wifi, imac

I have several computers at home but only my iMac is having wi-fi problems - around once a day wi-fi stops responding. When I turn my wireless off and immediately back on, it works again. Is this a hardware problem? Software problem?

I'm running a newish iMac running Lion and an Airport Express on Comcast.

EDIT: I should mention that nothing has changed in my setup aside from some software updates. Basically, I am trying to determine if this is a hardware or software problem and was hoping to find out what steps I can take to investigate.

Thanks!

Comment: There is absolutely not enough information here to provide you with any help. We need details on your network configuration, any log files that pertain, AE configuration, etc. It could be a DHCP problem, or it could be something else entirely. No way of knowing without much more detail.

Comment: @cksum: pls tell me how I can give you more detail

Comment: Have you run any software updates? The initial release of Lion had an issue where the wifi would stop working periodically - the fix would be to turn Airport off and back on. Apple have fixed this in the latest updates AFAIK

Comment: I always run the software updates.

Comment: Uhh ... could be just about anything.  For example:  When I'm in the living room, the kitchen lies between me and my office.  When my girlfriend turns on the microwave, my wifi cuts out from interference.  Same thing can happen with cordless phones.  Have you gone through the system.log (console)?  It could be interference, software problem, even hardware.  There's just not enough information.